# Wrong currenccy icon when export to pdf with syncfusion

Tags: syncfusion

I have a Datatable like this [image]

I use syncfusion version 7.403.0.20 to export PDF but some currency icon wrong.

[image]

How to fix it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have created the sample to display the currency symbols. Currency symbols are recognized as Unicode format in PDF.
So we have to apply the Unicode is true. Please refer the following code snippet:

C#:

```
//Creates a table
PdfGrid grid = new PdfGrid();

// apply  Unicode font

grid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.Font = new PdfTrueTypeFont(font, true);

//Draw the table

grid.Draw(page, new PointF(10, 10));
```

Please refer the sample in the below link :

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/PdfGridsample-1200681077.zip

Please try this and let us know if you have any further assistance .

Thanks ,

Abirami.